# Why the leading semicolon in JQuery ui.core.js?

Tags: jquery-ui

I found the beginning of the code of ui.core.js of JQuery UI quite interesting,

```
;jQuery.ui || (function($) {
// code...
})(jQuery);
```

What is the reason to have ';' in the front?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is there for concatenation purposes in case one would want to concatenate this file at the end of another script. It effectively fool-proofs concatenation to scripts that have not been terminated properly by a semi-colon.

So, given the following script:

```
alotOfJsCode(argument);
var fileEnd = noSemiColon
```

The semi-colon at the beginning allows to prevent this:

```
alotOfJsCode(argument);
var fileEnd = noSemiColonjQuery.ui || (function($) { //...
```

Which would cause the code to fail.

In JavaScript, a semi-colon all by itself has no syntactic value. The following two statements are the same:

```
//Statement 1
;;; ;; ; alert('hello world!'); ;;; ;; ;;

//Statement 2
alert('hello world!');
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that was valid JavaScript. +1